# Python, get data with beautiful soup; save data in array to approach each value separately

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

***Using Python 3.8 on Windows 10***

Using the beautifull_soup lib I retrieve data from a webserver. But I want to save each row in a, for example, an array, so it is possible to approach each value separately.
Can someone help me out? Another idea's to store the data is welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Python code to get data**

```
# importing system_lib
import sys
import os

# importing lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests     

def get_data():

        url = 'http://192.168.2.115:8080/Job/List/Company'


        # Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
        html_content = requests.get(url).text

        # Parse the html content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

        # Get all the headings of Lists
        table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'job-list-table'})
        table_body = table.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr', attrs={'data-area-id':'Company'})

        num = 0
        for row in rows:
            #Get all rows
            cols = row.find_all('td')

            #Order rows per ID
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            print(num, cols)
            num += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        get_data()
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
    finally:
        print("Done")
```

**Output:**

```
0 ['776792bb', 'Pickup', 'Pending', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 11:00:22 +02:00', '0', '', 'Idle', 'None']      
1 ['9ab377ab', 'Pickup', 'Failed', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 10:13:22 +02:00', '-1', '', 'Cancelled', 'None'] 
2 ['4bb6d2c3', 'Pickup', 'Failed', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 10:13:40 +02:00', '-1', '', 'Cancelled', 'None'] 
3 ['f9128016', 'Pickup', 'Failed', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 10:13:58 +02:00', '-1', '', 'Cancelled', 'None'] 
4 ['c88b3fd7', 'Pickup', 'Failed', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 10:14:16 +02:00', '-1', '', 'Cancelled', 'None'] 
5 ['a07c4e56', 'Pickup', 'Failed', 'SB', 'SC', '21/05/2021 10:14:35 +02:00', '-1', '', 'Cancelled', 'None']
```

Comment: You can append(num, cols) to another array which is defined outside of the for-loop right?

Comment: I suggest the use of a pytho dict, that way you have key, value pairs to work with

Comment: How do you need to access them? If you add some examples to your question it could help us understand what the best way to store the data is

Answer (score 1):

You could throw it into a datframe with pandas, and use `.loc()` or `.iloc()` to call out specific rows/cells.

```
def get_data():
        url = 'http://192.168.2.115:8080/Job/List/Company'

        # Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
        html_content = requests.get(url).text
        df = pd.read_html(html_content, attrs={'id':'job-list-table'})[0]

        print(df)
        
        # To store it, just write to file
        df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```